# Publications in differential geometry

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology, advice, research

I am a senior year mathematics undergraduate who is reading "Analysis on manifolds" by Munkres  and "topology from a differentiable viewpoint" by Milnor. I would like to know how can I find a simple problem, which can be solved within an year and has the potential of publishing?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to consider applying for some program like [Research Experiences for Undergraduates  (REU)](https://www.nsf.gov/funding/pgm_summ.jsp?pims_id=5517).

If you are an Indian, there are some programs for undergraduates. I can give more information  if you are interested.

Have a look at https://math.uchicago.edu/~may/ which has links for VIGRE/REU programs for each year.

You can look at for example http://math.uchicago.edu/~may/REU2016/. You get to see papers by participants some of which are original works. Some are just an exposition of which is already known. You pick some paper whose title is interesting and you can start reading it. It gives an idea of how the program works.